# Is wavelet analysis useful for 1D signals?

Tags: discrete-signals

Wavelets seem to be very useful for image processing. Assuming that I'm only ever going to study signals of time, i.e. 1D signals, should I still take a course in wavelet analysis? Are they applicable to 1D signals?

Comment: Very much so! I have used them for de-noising applications. (Here is one example http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/peak-detection-approach/1324#1324) Although I do not have the wavelet processing toolbox in MATLAB so I have to write them up myself. :-/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They absolutely are applicable. They are used for signal compression, denoising, feature extraction, filter-bank signal processing and many more things. In fact, a course of wavelet analysis will (should) stress one-dimensional analysis, which 2D is an extension of.

Comment: Can you give any examples how wavelet analysis could help decision-making? Assume you have 1D ECG signal. How can you benefit from wavelet analysis?